# Exclude all except 1 subdirectory from teamcity checkout rule

Tags: teamcity

I have a VCS root with the following checkout rules:

```
+:.
-:externals
+:externals/jQuery
```

However TeamCity doesn't seems to do a checkout for `externals/jQuery` directory.
Is there anyway to achive this, except by creating a separate VCS root for this directory?
I'm using TeamCity 8.0 latest EAP.

**Update (2017)**

Since TeamCity 10 it's seems that it's possible to do what this question was asking

```
+:**/* => target_directory
-:**/folder1 => target_directory
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene did you manage to find a solution to this? I want to do exactly the same.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I didn't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I would use something like this:  +:*  -:externals/someDir1  -:externals/someDir2.  Seems like you exclude all the content of external directory at line 2

Comment: Your solution is good in case of few directories that rarely change. Unfortunately, for me, it wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to checkout only the externals/jquery directory and nothing else, add this in your checkout conditions .

```
+:externals/jQuery -> jQueryDir(custom name)
```

or

```
+:externals/jQuery -> .
```